# Difference between such trash and such a trash

Tags: articles, difference

What is the difference between the following two sentences

> You must not read **such trash**
>
> You must not read **such a trash**

Or are they both the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You must not read such trash.** Trash, meaning "something which is waste or of no value" is a non-count noun, so you would not use an article such as "a" before it.

> trash
>
> noun [ Uncountable ]
>
> anything that is worthless and of low quality;
>   waste:

[Trash](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/trash)

Comment: You should not read such book, you should not read such a book, are they both correct and same?

Comment: Only "...such **a** book". is correct. Non-count noun: no article. Count noun: use article.